# how to convert list to map in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have the following list

```
({:Col1 {:type varchar :nullable true}} {:Col2 {:type varchar :nullable true}} {:Col3 {:type varchar :nullable false}})
```

And want to convert to the following

```
{:Col3 {:type varchar, :nullable false}, :Col1 {:type varchar, :nullable true}, Col2 {:type varchar, :nullable true}}
```

I am using the following code.

```
(def a '({:Col1 {:type varchar :nullable true}} {:Col2 {:type varchar :nullable true}} {:Col3 {:type varchar :nullable false}}))

 (apply hash-map (flatten (map (comp flatten seq) a)))
```

But is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is to use [merge](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/merge):

```
(reduce merge
        '({:Col1 {:type varchar :nullable true}} {:Col2 {:type varchar :nullable true}} {:Col3 {:type varchar :nullable false}}))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Symfrog's answer, this option is equally short, but may be a little bit easier to understand:

```
(apply merge a)
```

where `a` is defined as a sequence of maps, as in your question.

You can also use

```
(reduce conj a)
```

which is roughly how [`merge` is defined](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2751) in the Clojure source.